# Update from Loki to Juno stable?

Tags: release-loki, updates

now as Juno (0.5) is stable and released, how can one update from loki? I only find questions regarding the beta release. Is there a way to perform the update with apt? Is is save to edit the sources.list?

Comment: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/5089/170, https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/5617/170, https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/13635/170

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the "suggested" upgrade path is to install Juno from scratch,
and if you have your `/home` as a separate partiton might be the *best* method to be safe, I've just updated both my PCs with the `apt` method and all went well.

Since Juno is based on Ubuntu 18.04 (`bionic`) while Loki in based on 16.04 (`xenial`)
it was a simple matter of substituting all occurrences of `xenial` with `bionic` on `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.

The exact procedure was:

1. Copied in a backup directory all custom files on `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (i.e. all files but `appcenter.list`, `elementary.list` and `patches.list`) which are *custom* sources with specific mods for elementaryOS. These need to be update along with "standard" Ubuntu packages;
2. Made sure my system was up to date (`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`) before editing my source files;
3. *Removed* my custom lists from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (of which I had a backup copy as per #1). For example I have custom sources for Google Chrome, `wine`, `virtualbox`, etc. which are neither in standar Ubuntu repos nor in elementary OS ones;
4. Substituted all occurrences of `xenial` with `bionic` (i.e. `sudo sed 's/xenial/bionic/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo sed 's/xenial/bionic/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`;
5. Log out from graphical system (just to be safe, it *might* work even logged into the graphical desktop);
6. Open a console terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>);
7. Logged in and shut down graphical system (`sudo systemctl stop lightdm`);
8. Upgraded my system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
9. Rebooted and checked that all went well;
10. Restored all my custom sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (and substituted `xenial` with `bionic` where applicable);
11. Another pass of: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade all the software which came from custom sources.

`apt` was complaining of a missing GPG key during the `sudo apt update` at #8:

```
Err:4 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease                       
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A74F73EFFE70B91C
```

which was resolved with

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A74F73EFFE70B91C
sudo apt update
```

Also, on one of my PCs, I had a conflict with the package `linux-tools-4.15.0-36-generic` which I resolved with

```
 sudo apt-get purge linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-36 linux-tools-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-tools-4.15.0-36-generic
```

and then resumed the upgrade with

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

A final touch was:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

to remove unused/obsoleted packages.

Obviously, if you choose to follow this path (and if you choose to install Juno from scratch, too) it's *always* a good idea to have a full backup of your system. Well, it should be a good idea to have an up to date backup of your data even if *not* upgrading.

A little annoyance was that Juno completely dropped support for "system tray icons". This has **nothing** to do with the upgrade, it's a "feature" of Juno, and I was a little surprised that, for example, Dropbox icon wasn't showing. Again, it has **nothing** to do with the upgrade, and [there's a workaround](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators) which works for fresh installs, too.

Comment: **better strongly recommend backup of all important data!!**  -- and then, if it doesn't work (I'm a bit skeptical: is it possible to go from 16.04 to 18.04 directly, even in Ubuntu?) - well, there is the cleaner way of installing Juno from scratch. - Very interesting anyway. The tty update/upgrade might be the trick.

Comment: @cipricus You're right about backing up and reinstalling, I'm editing my answer right now. Also, I've upgraded tons of Ubuntu systems from LTS to LTS versions, with a simple `do-release-upgrade` ;)

Comment: This is indeed worth a try in  my case, never heard about this in elementary. Only here (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5092/170) there is a beginning of a discussion. Could you give as much info as possible in your answer as what each step is doing? could you explain how your solution fixes the problem mentioned by @ounos in a comment under the linked answer? - namely `: an LTS to LTS upgrade it's possible of course when we are talking about Ubuntu. The problem with elementary OS is that during upgrade all third party sources are disabled including eOS ppa`

Comment: @cipricus The _usual_ method for Ubuntu is indeed the command `do-release-upgrade`, which **disables** third party repositories. With this "manual" method, you're upgrading those, too. Obviously, this method it can be used on Ubuntu, too, but they have their published (and tested!) procedure and it's usually worth sticking to that.

Comment: what abour eOS ppa? have you added the new juno ones or have replaces "loki" with "juno" as you did for xenial/bionic? or that isn't even necessary?

Comment: @cipricus I don't have any ppa on my system which references `loki` or `juno`. If you're talking about `appcenter.list`, `patches.list`, etc, they simply had `xenial` which I changed to `bionic`. I think eOS ppa's just use the Ubuntu version they're based on.

Comment: @MrShunz your soloution worked for me. Marked your answer as solved :)

Comment: I literally just used this method to upgrade from Elementary OS 5.1 to 6.1. It all works like a charm and it took only less than 20 mins

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good writeup.  I used it twice to update 2 laptops for my family.  The only additional steps I did are:

1. take a screenshot of the dock, so you remember what apps were on the dock, and can put icons back in the same order after the update
2. `sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-ayatana` when the upgrade is complete
3. `sudo apt-get remove appstream-data-pantheon-loki*` when the upgrade is complete (2 packages will match and be removed)
4. Select a new desktop background, as the old ones we had from Loki were removed