# How to update from elementary OS loki to juno?

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, release-juno

I installed elementary 0.4.1 and update it. But doesn't update to elementary 5.0 Juno. please tell me how can i update to Juno. i want Juno no matter what..........

Please Help me .  I don't want to reinstall elementary OS for 5.0 Juno.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to update from an elementary version to another one. You have to clean install every time.

Hopefully in the next version they will add the option to update.

Comment: This is _the answer_, there's no rolling release in elementaryOS. Suraj Kushwah mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

[Update from Loki to Juno stable?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16482/update-from-loki-to-juno-stable)

I did that, basically. Many repositories afterwards showed arror when updating, and I had to fix them, but I have now what can be very similar to a freshly installed Juno. Your mileage can vary.