# home folder and its contents remain on the partition, after clean install for upgrade to Juno, but inaccessible

Tags: release-loki, release-juno, updates, home

I wanted to upgrade from Loki to Juno, with a low bandwidth internet connection, and to save time and effort, etc. So, I tried to use the method from this link:
[Update from Loki to Juno stable?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16482/update-from-loki-to-juno-stable)

But, something went wrong and I ended up with a black login screen without a field to enter password. So, returning to good old plan B, I decided to go with the option of a clean installation.

Please see steps below, to help me identify the mistake and also for a chronology of events:

1. Step 1: install loki again (since i had a bootable flash drive with
   loki)
2. Step 2: install unetbootin
3. Step 3: prepare a bootable flash drive with Juno
4. Step 4: boot and fast forward to installation options
5. Step 5: select 'something else' and choose hard disk partitions for /, home and swap
6. Step 6: select a 50GB partition with loki to format and install /, select remaining part of the hard disk for /home without formatting to retain old home folder of loki from before the decision to upgrade (did I mention that I don't have any backup of this folder?), setup a small swap.

Now, when I boot into Juno, I see that /home folder draws a blank. 180 GB data remains hidden somewhere. I have come across variations of this problem, but it was easier for others, since, it showed up a separate partition in most cases.

Thanks in advance. Please ignore errors in formatting this question.

Comment: the `/home` partition, is that in the same partition where you installed the system again?

Comment: No @Hasan. I have installed the os is on a 50gb, '/' partition. This partition had Loki on it. I have another partition of around 400gb with /home of Loki on it. I marked this /home again (without formatting) during step 5, and maybe that overlaid new folders, on the old ones.