# Update from Loki to Hera stable?

Tags: release-loki, release-hera

I was stuck with my first linux MacBook Pro (17" 2007 core2 duo era) with no possibilities to either read an USB other than MacOS and it didn't recognize my CD-RW for installing something else, so I wondered if it was possible after all to update from Loki 0.4.1 to Hera 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that it is possible and that the result is great! Hera uses seemlessly (I didn't check) less ressources, runs smoother, and close lid suspend/resume is now working fine and fully supported.

Now please backup everything first, and take my word of caution: I did encounter a small error but it could be solved along the way, but you have to be ready to work it out in console-only mode. I really advise to do so to avoid upgrade issues.

I recommend to follow [this post's green V'd reply](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16482/update-from-loki-to-juno-stable)

Nevertheless, I followed a simpler route than in the above post reply: I only backed up the indicated files in the post, but I didn't remove them, and I only did that and the update worked fine.

Look in advance for the way to log off graphical mode on Loki:
This worked for me:

```
session=`loginctl session-status | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
loginctl terminate-session $session
```

The error that I encountered is as follows:

```
libdvd-pkg: 'apt-get check' failed
```

to which I did only the following (which was then fixed by simply resuming the update process):

```
sudo apt remove libdvd-pkg
```

I had to reboot and install from console again, as in recovery mode (push escape on reboot to reach grub), and from the login screen (Fn+Ctrl+Alt+F1) to go to login, login and password then restart the apt instructions again to continue the upgrade. My screen blacked out repetively due to the login mode timeout, but I could see by (Fn+Crtl+Alt+F1) again as many times as needed. It's a little adventurous for the less experienced but it worked!

Don't forget to clean everything as the post indicates, by

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Once the whole upgrade procedure is done.

The update goes straight from Loki to Hera.

Enjoy!